# Why is (self.window) in the following code a condition?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why is `(self.window)` in the following code a condition?

```
-(void)beginRefreshing {
      [UIView animateWithDuration:MJRefreshFastAnimationDuration
                       animations:^{
                         self.alpha = 1.0;
                       }];
      self.pullingPercent = 1.0;
      if (self.window) {
        self.state = MJRefreshStateRefreshing;
      } else {
        self.state = MJRefreshStateWillRefresh;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
      }
}
```

Comment: Context?  What class is this?

Comment: a UITableView RefreshComponent ,Inherited from UIView

Comment: The purpose of the check is to see if the view is within the view hierarchy, which you could find out by reading the class reference for the `window` property of `UIView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain variables are boolean meaning they can either be equal to true or false. Others can have a wide range of values. for example off you want to do something if an Integer is equal to 5 you can write:

```
if (myInt == 5) { 
  //do something 
}
```

If your variable is a Boolean there are only two options so we can write is shorter:

```
if (myBoolean) {
  //case where myBoolean = true
} else {
  //case where myBoolean = false
}
```

In your particular example, `self.window` evaluates to a Boolean in the following manner: either self.windows exists in the view hierarchy or not (`self.windows == true`) or it do not (`self.windows == false`).

Comment: Note that `self.window` is a pointer, not a boolean. It's just that when used in the context of an `if` statement, `if (self.window)` is equivalent to `if (self.window != nil)`

Comment: no, I agree that it evaluates to a boolean. Mostly I was clarifying for the OP that although it evaluates to a boolean _in this particular context_, the variable itself isn't of boolean type; it's a pointer. For example, you couldn't assign to it by saying `self.window = true;`, and the comparison `if (self.window)` is shorthand for `if (self.window != nil)`, not `if (self.window == true)`

Comment: It's actually a side effect, AFAIK. Because `false` is defined as `0`, and `true` is defined as anything different than `0`. A valid address is non-zero, it is treated as `true`, whereas, thanks to ARC, `nil == 0`. You can check this by printing this `NSLog(@"%p", nil)`. Bear in mind, that for integers, this means that a negative value, also evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
if (self.window) {
```

which is a short version of

```
if (self.window != nil) {
```

is a test whether the view (`UIView` instance) is in the view hierarchy of any window, that is, whether the view is displayed on the screen.

Comment: The view can actually be invisible, either by setting its `alpha` to `0`, or by setting its `hidden` property to `YES`.

Comment: @Losiowaty I know that. I have decided to ignore that for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to expand my comment to an answer for future reference.

It's actually a side effect, AFAIK. Because false is defined as `0`, and true is defined as anything different than `0`. A valid objects address is non-zero so it is treated as true, whereas, thanks to ARC, `nil == 0`. You can check this by printing this `NSLog(@"%p", nil)`. Bear in mind, that for integers, this means that a negative value, also evaluates to true

It is also worth noting, that because the underlying storage for a `boolean` is rarely one-bit it may not always be true that `when someBool == true, then someBool == 1`. This means that taking such a shortcut :

```
- (NSInteger)increment:(NSInteger)toIncrement ifTrue:(BOOL)condition {
    return toIncrement + condition;
}
```

may not always lead to `toIncrement` being incremented by `1`. The code is valid, becasue a `BOOL` will get promoted to integer automatically.

This is of course somwhat of an edge case, but still possible.

Comment: The value of `nil` in Objective-C has always been zero, but that has nothing to do with ARC.